# ArrayField or multiple tables in PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql

I am working with postgreSQL and I wanted to design a schema for database. I have a data whcich is not very complexed.
My data is something like this:

```
{
title: 'title'
location: 'location'
image: 'url'
artists: ['artist 1', 'artist 2', 'artist 3']
songs: ['song 1', 'song 2' , 'song 3', 'song 4']
}
```

my question is related to storing artists and songs what would be best approach generally in database to create one table and store all the data in it with songs and artists as ArrayField for this option I've heard it will be against the 1NF. The second option is to have separate table for artists and songs have them related to the main table?

Which of these options are the best practices in schema designing?

Comment: Go with tables. You will expend more energy wrapping and unwrapping arrays then it takes to create the tables and populate them.

Comment: PostgreSQL is a relational database. Relational databases work best with relational data. Stick to 3NF

Answer (score 2):

There are cases when using denormalization is needed and a good idea, but only if you have a *specific* query that you need to optimize, and you can't get the optimization you need by storing data in a normalized fashion.

Using normalization gives you the most flexibility for different types of queries against your data.

For example, if you store the artists and songs in arrays as you show above, how would you search for all data for `artist 2`? If you need a variety of queries against the data, it is probably best practice to use the normalized design, using a many-to-many table for each multi-valued attribute.

If you never need to optimize that query (either you never need the query at all, or else when you run that query, it's acceptable for it to be inefficient), and you frequently need to optimize queries for the data with arrays of aggregated artists and songs, then you may choose to use the denormalized design you show.

So either design may be the best practice, for different situations.

Your job as a professional software developer is to understand the business priorities, and choose the best design for the priorities you need to support.